# Change plot legend symbology in Geopandas

Tags: plot, legend, geopandas

I am trying to change the river symbol on my map legend. It is currently a light blue line in the legend; however, I want to change it to be a brigher blue (such as #1F45FC) squiggly line. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

My Current Map
[NC map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnL3d.png)

Example of desired symbology
[Stream symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxdMM.png)

This is the code I am currenly using; however, I don't know what I need to add in the code to obtain the legend symbology I want (brigher blue (such as #1F45FC) squiggly line).

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 8))
nc.plot(facecolor='Grey', edgecolor='black', ax=ax, zorder=1)
hydro_NAD83.plot(ax=ax, markersize=3,linewidth = .3, color='blue', label = 'Rivers', zorder = 2)
colleges_NAD83.plot(ax=ax, markersize=10, color='#B93B8F', alpha = 1, label = 'NC Colleges and Universities', zorder=3)
ax.legend(fontsize=12,
          frameon=True,
          loc=('lower left'),)
```